# Atomic variable c++

Tags: c++, multithreading

I have count initialized as

```
count = 15;
```

and if I have two threads like this:

```
thread_1(){
    count = 0;
    x = count;
    count = x;
}
```

and

```
thread_2(){
    y = count;
    count = y;
    count = 0;
}
```

Without count being synchronized, count can end up being 15 after running the two threads.

If I declare my count variable as atomic, will count always be 0 after running the two threads?

Comment: "*If I declare my count variable as atomic, will count always be 0 after running the two threads?*" - why not just run the code and find out for yourself?

Comment: You can use critical_section for setting count. Finally count will be zero

Comment: As written the behavior of the code is undefined. So, yes, `count` can end up being 15. Or it can end up being 42, or 17, or it might crash.

Comment: @RemyLebeau, The OP effectively is asking whether the behavior of the program is defined or not.  Running a program to find out what it does on one particular OS and one particular hardware platform after building it with one particular tool chain will not tell you what it _could do_ using some other OS/platform/toolchain if undefined behavior is a possibility.

Comment: Data race on non-atomic object is undefined behavior.

Comment: @xskxzr I am not 100% clear on the _formal_ meaning of "undefined behavior," when it appears in the C++ standard, but the outcome of a data race on `std::atomic` variables is "undefined" in the conventional meaning of the word.  Even if `count` and `x` and `y` are all declared as `std::atomic<int>`, the value of `count` after both threads have completed depends on how the assignments are interleaved.  (See ensc's answer, below.)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

no; program can be executed like

1. `count = 15`  (global initialization)
2. `y = count`  (thread2)
3. `count = 0`  (thread1)
4. `count = y`  (thread2 -> 15)
5. `x = count`  (thread1)
6. `count = 0`  (thread2)
7. `count = x`  (thread1 -> 15)

Answer (score 0):

No. First of all, your operations are likely already atomic, as in they change `count` all at once. C++ atomics are really for things like `count = count + 5`, where you need to load `count`, add 5 to it, and store it back. Instead, what you need is to make each of those sections atomic, and for that you can use a `std::mutex`, like so:

```
int count = 15;
std::mutex mutex;

void thread_1(void){
    //Locks the mutex and unlocks when it goes out of scope
    std::lock_guard<std::mutex> guard(mutex); 
    count = 0;
    x = count;
    count = x;
}
void thread_2(void){
    //alternatively:
    mutex.lock()
    y = count;
    count = y;
    count = 0;
    mutex.unlock()
}
```

Comment: No, the original operations are not atomic. There's more to atomic than speculating about whether a read or store might get torn. If a non-atomic variable is accessed from more than one thread and one or more of those accesses is a write the behavior of the program is undefined.

Comment: Note, too, that, although making both functions mutually exclusive resolves the data race, it misses the point of the code. Code like this is typically intended to explore how load and store orders and memory ordering specifiers interact and affect the possible results. Blowing away all those issues makes the code predictable and consistent, but hides the underlying questions.